# Is there a way to render components inside TextInput?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to render @ mentions on TextInput, I tried passing the required components and text as an array inside TextInput.

It works but once the input is changed the mentions are getting converted to just plain text. Is there any way to preserve the rendered components and prevent it from being converted to plain text?

Code:

```
  renderMessageWithMentions = (messageText: string) => {
    const mentionsRegExp = /<@(.*?)>/g;
    const mentionUIDs = R.match(mentionsRegExp, messageText).map(mention => {
      let filteredStr = mention.replace(/<@/g, "");
      filteredStr = filteredStr.replace(/>/g, "");
      return filteredStr;
    });

    return R.map(text => {
      if (mentionUIDs.includes(text)) {
        return <Mention uid={text} />;
      }

      return text;
    }, R.split(mentionsRegExp, messageText));
  };
```

Mentions are formatted like this `<@UID>`. Here I'm looping over the `messageText` and if it's a mention, I'm returning Mention component which will render the user's name in blue text else returning plain text.

This what I'm rendering:

```
  setText = text => {
    const { isTrackingStarted, previousChar } = this.state;
    const lastChar = text.substr(text.length - 1);
    const wordBoundry = R.trim(previousChar).length === 0;

    if (lastChar === "@" && wordBoundry) {
      this.startTracking();
    } else if ((lastChar === " " && isTrackingStarted) || text === "") {
      this.stopTracking();
    }

    this.setState({ text, previousChar: lastChar });
  };

<TextInput onChangeText={this.setText}>
  {this.renderMessageWithMentions(messageText)}
</TextInput>
```

[image: Image: Before changing text]

[image: Image: After changing text]

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of how it looks before and after the change as well as how the array content looks like?